# SQL aggregate and filter functions

Tags: sql

Consider following table:

```
Number | Value
1        a
1        b
1        a
2        a
2        a
3        c
4        a
5        d
5        a
```

I want to choose every row, where the value for one number is the same, so my result should be:

```
Number | Value
2        a
3        c
4        a
```

I manage to get the right numbers by using nested
SQL-Statements like below. I am wondering if there is a simpler solution for my problem.

```
SELECT 
a.n,
COUNT(n)
FROM 
(
SELECT number n , value k 
FROM testtable
GROUP BY number, value
) a
GROUP BY n
HAVING COUNT(n) = 1
```

Comment: Huh?  I don't understand your logic.  Where does 3/c come from?  And your query returns two columns as *numbers* so it is nothing like your result set.

Comment: Because there is only one specific value for number 3. I want the number 3 to be in my result set. I want to exclude all numbers where two different values exist.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 3/c is the onlyNumber-Value-Combination for 3, just like 4/a. For 1 you have 1/a and 1/b so that is not a solution for the request,

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Comment: @OcasoProtal . . . and just like 2/a?

Comment: Do you want to get `1` in the second column (like with your query), or the actual value (like with the responses so far)? @GordonLinoff, yes, for `2` the only value is `a`, it doesn't matter that it is twice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff exactly: the only combination is 2/a, even if this combination comes twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT NUMBER,MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE FROM TESTTABLE
GROUP BY NUMBER
HAVING MAX(VALUE)=MIN(VALUE)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I would just give the second column a name: `MAX(VALUE) AS Value`.

Comment: This seems really helpful! Thanks! :)

Comment: In this approach you can [set collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503703/sql-server-understanding-how-mintext-works) also.

Answer (score 3):

You can try also this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.number, t.value
FROM testtable t
LEFT JOIN testtable t_other
  ON t.number = t_other.number AND t.value <> t_other.value
WHERE t_other.number IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `exists`.

```
select distinct num, val from testtable a
where not exists (
  select 1 from testtable b
  where a.num = b.num
  and a.val <> b.val
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd080dd/5